# Kofax Total Agility: moving a document job programmatically to a specific process step

Tags: c#, kofax

I am working on Kofax Total Agility with a basic BPMN (Business Process Model and Notation).
This process contains differents steps:

- classification
- document review
- data extraction
- document validation & verification
- a c# external call
- finally an export

[image]

My objective is to make future processes easier to manage by developping modules.
In the Workspace, I can import documents and manage all the process and export document in the end and it work fine.

I tried to find in the API documentation the Services and Methods that can be called and used externally. In this process, When I reach the externalCall step of the process I would like to return to the classification step or the document review depending on a value retrieved in the verification step.

Passing a variable from verification to externalCall is easy. My issue is to know how to "move" an activity to a previous step programmatically for one or several document imported in a process. In this case i would like to reassign a document to validation step or extraction step after verification and externalCall in the workflow.

I found method such as ReassignActivity which is in ActivityService. My question would be to know how to get the required variables to make it possible. For example, how do I retrieve the ResourceIdentity object (original and new resource), the JobActivityIdentity object, etc. Do I need to create a new Job ? if yes, do i have to get the jobId of the previous job ?

Comment: Is there a more in-depth reason why need the complication of doing this programmatically?  The simple approach is to just use a decision node (or a few of them) to decide whether the process flows to export or to a previous activity.

Comment: Personnaly I do not have any reason... My firm does have such requirement. I think I found information here : https://docshield.kofax.com/KTA/en_US/7.7.0-o3xtk9orwd/help/API/latest/capturesdksamples.html I do have a use programmatic use case. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out a solution. I created a dll that allows me to create a new Job and delete previous job at a certain point of a workflow.

For this I used the JobIdentity CreateJobAndStartAt method. At this stage, it's rather easy to get the sessionId required because it's a system variable.

Basically, I implemented a method this way :

```
public class AppJobService
{
    public JobIdentity CreateJobAndStartAt(string sessionId, string jobIdentityId)
    {
        JobIdentity returnValue = null;
        var js = new sdk.JobService();

        var pai = new ProcessActivityIdentity();
        pai.ActivityName = Constants.activityName;

        var pi = new ProcessIdentity();
        pi.Name = Constants.processIdentityName;

        try
        {
            returnValue = js.CreateJobAndStartAt(sessionId, pi, new JobInitialization(), pai);

            // call terminate job
            JobIdentity currentJi = new JobIdentity();
            currentJi.Id = jobIdentityId;
            TerminateJob(sessionId, currentJi);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    void TerminateJob(string sessionId, JobIdentity jobIdentity)
    {
        var js = new sdk.JobService();
        try
        {
            js.TerminateJob(sessionId, jobIdentity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine !
My questions are the following:

1. is there a way to retrieve dynamically the process name and pass it as variable ? At this stage I hard coded it : Constants.activityName
2. is there also a way to pass a variable to this new Job ? for example a boolean that returns true if the dll was called or not
3. is there a way to retrieve the previous activity name ? it could be useful if i plan to reuse the method at different step of the process and create a new job one step before